# one thousand visitors on Sunday and Monday

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

a. The museum had one thousand visitors on Sunday and Monday.

Is that one thousand per day or is the sum of the visitors of the two days one thousand?

Many thanks

Comment: It's ambiguous. But if it was intended to mean "one thousand per day", a halfway competent speaker would say *"...on **both** Sunday and Monday"*.

Comment: The short answer here is "context would decide." If you found this sentence out of context, or invented it, then there's no real point to trying to guess. If it's a "real" sentence with a context, please edit to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence, spoken with a bit of ambiguity, implies a total attendance of one thousand individuals over the course of both Sunday and Monday.
While, the visitor count of one thousand is a cumulative figure for the two consecutive days, the sentence does not provide information about how the number of visitors was distributed between Sunday and Monday, but it **highlights the combined attendance for both days**.

Comment: As you say it's ambiguous. It would probably be used to mean a combined total, but could mean a per day figure depending on context (which the OP does not provide). It would certainly be OK to say something like "Visitor numbers varied from day to day. The museum had one thousand visitors on Sunday and Monday." meaning per day.

Comment: Thank you all so much. How about: "The museum had one thousand visitors on Sunday and on Monday." Would that mean one thousand per day?